# Changing ViewController from an UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, viewcontroller

I'm trying to change the ViewController when an area in a pic is pressed.
I tried doing this :

```
-(void)openDrawer{
    UIStoryboard *mStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc =[mStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DrawViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

}
```

but self.navigationController does not exist, that is understandable, but I can not find a way to get a the current viewController with in the Image

I tried putting it in a different class, delegating from the viewController of the current view.

```
-(void) changeChangeViewToName:(NSString *)name{
    UIStoryboard *mStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc =[mStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:name];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

This works from inside the viewController but I can't call the function from inside the Image.

Answer (score 1):

Post a notification from the class (image?) that decides it wants the new view controller displayed.  Listen for that notification in the existing view controller that is capable of doing the push.

Answer (score 0):

Phillip Mills is right. You could also use the delegate pattern:

1. Create a protocol for objects that should be able to perform the desired action:

   ```
   @protocol YourImageDelegate 
     -(void)touchUpInsideArea;
   @end
   ```
2. Add this method to your view controller:

   ```
   -(void)touchUpInsideArea {
     [self openDrawer];
   }
   ```
3. Set up your view controller to conform to the protocol:

   ```
   @interface YourViewController : UIViewController
   ```

And don't forget to include your protocol in both files: the view controller class and the image class.